# Visual studio 2013 regex find match multi line

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-2013, find

I am trying to match multiple lines (and in the end replace parts of it)

The string I need to match;

```
    [UserRightAttribute(Function.Production, Function.IOControlCustomer, Function.IOControlIAI)]
    public Outputs Waterflow_On_Cmd { get; private set; }
```

My attempt:

```
(\t*\[UserRightAttribute\()(Function.Production)(.*\r\n)\t*public
```

It goes south when the regular expression tries to continue matching after the \r\n.

Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `\r\n` in your regex into a character class. Some files may or maynot contain `\r` carriage return character.

```
(\s*\[UserRightAttribute\()(Function\.Production)(.*[\r\n])\s*public
```

OR

```
(\t*\[UserRightAttribute\()(Function\.Production)(.*[\r\n])\t*public
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sD9zK6/3)

Comment: Hi, did you also try this in Visual Studio? It does the exact same thing. It matches until the end of the line as long as a do not specify '\t*public'. Once I specify more it no longer matches (no idea why though)

Comment: Yep, because `.*` would match upto the end of the line. is there really a `\t` exists? or replace `\t` with `\s`

Comment: that is `(\s*\[UserRightAttribute\()(Function\.Production)(.*[\r\n])\s*public`